# Can I create the [ionic-material] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I want to add the [ionic-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-material) tag.

[What Iconic Material is](https://web.archive.org/web/20200229035439/http://ionicmaterial.com:80/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [ionicmaterial.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929034818/http://ionicmaterial.com/assets/img/logo.png??v=0.0.1))</sub>

> Pour material design into your Ionic hybrid apps for all the sexy and
> no 
> complexity. Now unlock the depth, motion & ink specs of
> Google's material design with easy-to-add-on classes.

It's rather new, but there have been many questions about this lately:

1. [Ionic material app not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774871/ionic-material-app-not-running)
2. [Ionic Material Content not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895395/ionic-material-content-not-load)
3. [ionic app to ionic material or angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124518/ionic-app-to-ionic-material-or-angular-material)
4. [Using Ionic Material with Ionic and Cordova 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890007/using-ionic-material-with-ionic-and-cordova-5)

And [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=ionic%20material).

---

Would it be appropriate that I tag those questions listed with the [ionic-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-material) tag?

Comment: You know, we somewhat frown on marketing-babble, and your quote there really rubs me the wrong way. I hope nothing of it ever blemishes tag-wiki or excerpt...

Comment: Confused @Deduplicator can you reword please?

Comment: Well, that text you put into the quote is standard marketing-department material, in other words advertisement with maximal hyperbole and vagueness, but minimal content. It's no good for tag-wiki or tag-excerpt, read some of the major ones for examples, and the help-center page.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale I agree with Deduplicator and I would say even this post smells like self promotion to me (since you include a lot of non-relevant information about Ionic Material that does nothing but promote the product).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see a problem with it, but there are a few things to note first:

- You're going to want to write a decent usage excerpt and explain how it differs from Angular Material.
- If you add them to those existing questions, **edit those questions into shape.**  Don't *just* shoehorn the tag in.

Comment: The tag has by now been created, but has no [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-material/info), just an excerpt saying what you shouldn't use this tag for.